# Puppeteer click containing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

just wondering why Puppeteer wont click an element for me...

the code is as follows:

```
    var clickPhone = '//*[contains(@class, "ep-epage-sidebar__phone-button")]';
var showPhone = '//*[contains(@class, "ep-epage-phone-popup-number__button")]';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1200000);
await page.goto(url);

const cp = await page.$x(clickPhone);
if (cp) {
    page.click(cp)
}
const sp = await page.$x(showPhone);
if (sp) {
    page.click(sp);
}
```

everything is imported correctly above and below is just formatting.
But I need it to click through a button for me, which will open a modal, it will then click a button on that modal and scrape the data from there.

However I am met with a few different errors whenever I try and fix the code.

The errors that tend to be met are:

startsWith() is not a function.
Not a selector.

---

I have it to the point now where this code just runs a 'blank run', no output is received as 'cp' and 'sp' are both false due to errors, hence it doesn't even attempt to click anymore.

Comment: No way to say without seeing the page and code as a [mcve], but you need to `await` all promises, like `await cp.click()`. You may be blocked by a bot detector, there could be an iframe, the xpath might be wrong, the elements may need to be blocked using `waitForXPath`, there could be shadow roots...

Answer (score 0):

I think the $x function returns an array.

Try await cp[0].click()

Answer (score -2):

I’m having the same problem, got a slight fix but may not work 100% of the time.

You can try using document.click()